# For Loop alternative to dynamically filter and summarise millions of points

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a dataset with 5 million records in this format:

```
library(dplyr)
    
Data <- tibble(X=runif(5000000, min=200000, max=400000),
                Y=runif(5000000, min=400000, max=500000),
                UID = 1:5000000,
                Count = runif(5000000, min=1, max=2000))
```

For each UID, I need to summarise 1) the number of other points 2) the count sum of the other points and 3) a density calculation of UIDs that are within 200m, 400m, 800m and 1600m. The final output required is a table with each UID and its summary output.

This for loop illustrates the output required, but would take weeks to complete:

```
Summary <- NULL

for (n in 1:nrow(Data)){
Data_Row <- Data[n,]

Row_200 <- Data %>% filter(between(X, Data_Row$X-200,Data_Row$X+200) &  between(Y, Data_Row$Y-200, Data_Row$Y+200)) %>%
    summarise(Instances_200 = n(), Count_200 = sum(Count), Calcualtion_200 = Count_200/(Instances_200*0.000625))

Row_400 <- Data %>% filter(between(X, Data_Row$X-400,Data_Row$X+400) &  between(Y, Data_Row$Y-400, Data_Row$Y+400)) %>%
    summarise(Instances_400 = n(), Count_400 = sum(Count), Calcualtion_400 = Count_400/(Instances_400*0.000625))

Row_800 <- Data %>% filter(between(X, Data_Row$X-800,Data_Row$X+800) &  between(Y, Data_Row$Y-800, Data_Row$Y+800)) %>%
    summarise(Instances_800 = n(), Count_800 = sum(Count), Calcualtion_800 = Count_800/(Instances_800*0.000625))

Row_1600 <- Data %>% filter(between(X, Data_Row$X-1600,Data_Row$X+1600) &  between(Y, Data_Row$Y-1600, Data_Row$Y+1600)) %>%
    summarise(Instances_1600 = n(), Count_1600 = sum(Count), Calcualtion_1600 = Count_1600/(Instances_1600*0.000625))

Summary_Row <- bind_cols(Data[n,"UID"], Row_200, Row_400, Row_800, Row_1600)

Summary <- bind_rows(Summary, Summary_Row)
}
```

I am aware of things like `lapply` and `map`, but I don't know how they could be used to do this dynamic filtering and summarisation more quickly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Mark my "answer" is more to show what the intended output is, rather than being a realistic way of solving my problem. It's a fair point that I didn't make that more explicit. Also, I'm sure I could ask this question on Code Review, but I personally don't see this question as off topic for here (perhaps with better wording). Unless there is something specific about the question means you don't feel it should be here? https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778:~:text=What%20you%20should,opinion%2Dbased.

Comment: @Chris I can't speak for others, but in my experience R is quite slow at many things when the data gets big, and when you're looking at finding the nearest neighbours of 5 million points, that's doubly so

Comment: @Chris but I do like this question! So maybe someone with more experience in these things can come along and help you solve it

Comment: I think there are specialized spatial algorithms to help with this sort of question. One approach is to segment your search area into hashes so you only do calculations on pairs of points that are within the same or adjacent hashes. In your example, your x range is 200k and your y range is 1000, so even in your largest window calc, 99.9% of points can be excluded from any calculation by looking at the hash first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750975/fastest-way-to-get-geo-distance-for-large-dataset-in-r/72755385#72755385

Comment: @Chris this is slightly tangential but you might find it interesting/useful to look at this [Advent of Code problem](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/23), and the corresponding [solutions people came up with](https://old.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/a8s17l/2018_day_23_solutions/). It's a similar kind of problem (albeit at a smaller scale). I think the creator intended for it to be solved with octrees, but people came up with many other interesting ways of solving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to understand OP's answer post, specifically the output table.

Focusing on the first row of the output table -- I see that `SC550650NE` is reported to have 20 instances of another point within 200 of `(X=255085.6, Y=465070.1)` and a sum-count of 24.

```
> Data[ID=="SC550650NE"]
          X        Y    UID Count         ID   distance
1: 255085.6 465070.1 832751  1908 SC550650NE 0.03272809
```

So I calculate the distance of all the points relative to `(X=255085.6, Y=465070.1)`.  And then display those that are within 200 in ascending order.  I count 29, not 20.  Also, when I sum the counts, I get 25,463, not 24.

```
> Data[,distance:=sqrt((X-255085.6)^2 + (Y-465070.1)^2)]
> Data[distance <= 200][order(distance)]
           X        Y     UID Count         ID     distance
 1: 255085.6 465070.1  832751  1908 SC550650NE   0.03272809
 2: 255093.6 465124.7 1371253  1513 SC550651SE  55.16468957
 3: 255034.2 465011.8 3512521   396 SC550650SW  77.73592845
 4: 255049.8 464993.6 2603353   255 SC550649NW  84.47194005
 5: 255091.7 465162.7  193893  1784 SC550651NE  92.82767523
 6: 254968.1 465083.5 2245518   186 SC549650NE 118.25898594
 7: 255180.5 464970.4 3376500   826 SC551649NE 137.66330325
 8: 255148.5 464947.4 3473247  1526 SC551649SW 137.86046404
 9: 255136.8 465202.7 2560816   212 SC551652SW 142.12504000
10: 255089.6 465224.3 2788575  1429 SC550652SE 154.24575868
11: 255213.6 465158.4 2051343   331 SC552651NW 155.52946932
12: 255234.1 465015.9  601896  1175 SC552650SW 158.08971475
13: 255231.4 464993.8 2562794  1209 SC552649NW 164.57602726
14: 255236.8 465003.9 2579822   624 SC552650SW 165.05736525
15: 255163.8 465219.0 2793140   491 SC551652SE 168.19129349
16: 254997.8 465224.2 3686855  1948 SC549652SE 177.38964783
17: 255055.7 464895.0 3850088  1904 SC550648NE 177.60704244
18: 254952.1 465189.1 4992168   668 SC549651NE 178.80180844
19: 255237.6 465165.5 3778801   950 SC552651NW 179.50253647
20: 255148.1 464900.4 2842521   204 SC551649SW 180.86815284
21: 255035.4 464891.2  933305   854 SC550648NW 185.79738782
22: 255245.6 465175.2 1453263   446 SC552651NW 191.44182598
23: 255227.8 465200.5 1557782   851 SC552652SW 192.90236356
24: 254894.7 465031.3  657336  1247 SC548650SE 194.79510938
25: 255102.8 464875.4 3051082   148 SC551648NW 195.41964698
26: 254914.2 464971.4 3090917    28 SC549649NW 197.75429388
27: 255030.4 464879.7  895456   109 SC550648NW 198.20424559
28: 255281.9 465101.9 3970383  1810 SC552651SE 198.85139040
29: 255108.3 465268.3 1968621   431 SC551652NW 199.51847902
           X        Y     UID Count         ID     distance
> Data[distance <= 200, sum(Count)]
[1] 25463
```

## Edit

### 5 million rows

So after ill-advisedly using the comments for discussion (sorry, SO!) we have a better sense of our situation.  @Chris has a solution that gives an approximation but this was a concession that was being made to try and lower the  computation time.  During the discussion, we also learned that the distance metric may be a square or a circle, and 4 cores are available on the machine.

I will present two solutions, one for the circle metric and one for the square metric.  The circle metric is faster.

Both follow the approach in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814035/2727349).

### Circle metric

- e.g. `distance = sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) ) <= 200`

```
library(tictoc)
library(data.table)
```

Pick one of the `num.rows`.  Start small and work up to get a sense of timing.  I have 32GB as well (on a mac) so I'm hoping it is comparable.  Roughly it seemed doubling the number of rows led to a 4x increase in computation time.

```
### Pick one:
###
### num.rows <-     4e4     ###   12 seconds on 4 nodes
### num.rows <-  0.078125e6 ###   43 seconds on 4 nodes
### num.rows <-  0.15625e6  ###  154 seconds on 4 nodes
### num.rows <-  0.3125e6   ###   10.5 min   on 4 nodes
### num.rows  <- 0.625e6    ###   44.  min   on 4 nodes
### num.rows  <- 1.25e6     ###  ~3 hours
### num.rows  <- 2.5e6      ###  ~12 hours
## num.rows  <- 5.0e6      ###  ~ 42.53 hours on 4 nodes VERIFIED.
 
set.seed(123)
   
# Input data
tbl.data <- data.table(
    X=runif(num.rows, min=200000, max=400000),
    Y=runif(num.rows, min=400000, max=500000),
    UID = 1:num.rows,
    Count = sample(1:2000,num.rows,replace=TRUE))

setkey(tbl.data, UID)

tbl.data

setkey(tbl.data, UID)
```

This approach depends on passing the entire X, Y, and Count columns of the dataset.  We denote them `Xvec`, `Yvec`, and `Cvec`, respectively.  From there we make a function, `instances()` that will first calculate the distance of 1 point `(x.in, y.in)` to all the other points in (`Xvec`, `Yvec`), calculate the instances and do the sumCount (the density "calculation" is done at the end and doesn't need to be done within this step or be parallelized).

This function, `instances()`, is made to be deployed within a data.table, and is setup to do so in the function `instances.stacked()`.  Since we are passing the entire entire X, Y, and Count columns of the dataset and operating row-wise in the original dataset, we can tackle the problem in parallel.  If we had `parallel::detectCores()` of 5 million, we'd have one core per row and be done in a jiffy.  However, we have 4, so we take a moment to make a variable `group_quarters` that will split the dataset into 4 chunks via `foo2()`'s deployment of `split_df()` (both of these adapted from the example in aforementioned SO post).

```
Xvec <- tbl.data$X
Yvec <- tbl.data$Y
Cvec <- tbl.data$Count

## based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814035/2727349
instances <- function(x=Xvec,y=Yvec, count=Cvec, x.in, y.in){
  
  calcdist <- sqrt( (x-x.in)^2+ (y-y.in)^2 )
  
  truth_1600 <- calcdist <= 1600
  result_1600 <- c("instances_1600" = sum( truth_1600 ), "sumCount_1600"= sum( Cvec*truth_1600))
  
  
  truth_0800 <- calcdist <=  800
  result_0800 <- c("instances_0800" = sum( truth_0800 ), "sumCount_0800"= sum( Cvec*truth_0800))

  
  truth_0400 <- calcdist <=  400
  result_0400 <- c("instances_0400" = sum( truth_0400 ), "sumCount_0400"= sum( Cvec*truth_0400))

  
  truth_0200 <- calcdist <=  200
  result_0200 <- c("instances_0200" = sum( truth_0200 ), "sumCount_0200"= sum( Cvec*truth_0200))
  
  result=c(result_0200, result_0400, result_0800, result_1600)
  return(result)
  
}
```

```
instances_stacked <- function(DT, x=Xvec,y=Yvec, count=Cvec){
  
  DT[,
     as.list(instances( x.in=X, y.in=Y)),
     by=c("UID")
     ]
  
}

split_df <- function(d, var) {
  base::split(d, get(var, as.environment(d)))
}
```

```
## define group_quarters roughly as 25% population
tbl.data[UID <  0.25 * num.rows                         , group_quarters:="1st q"]
tbl.data[UID <  0.50 * num.rows & UID >= 0.25 * num.rows, group_quarters:="2nd q"]
tbl.data[UID <  0.75 * num.rows & UID >= 0.50 * num.rows, group_quarters:="3rd q"]
tbl.data[                         UID >= 0.75 * num.rows, group_quarters:="4th q"]
tbl.data[, uniqueN(group_quarters)]
tbl.data[, table(group_quarters)]
```

```
foo2 <- function(dt) {
  dt2 <- split_df(dt, "group_quarters")
  require(parallel)
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4) ## 4 chosen based on parallel::detectCores()
  print(cl)
  clusterExport(cl, varlist= "instances_stacked") ## this was the `foo` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814035/2727349
  clusterExport(cl, varlist= "instances")
  clusterExport(cl, varlist= c("Xvec","Yvec","Cvec")) 
  clusterExport(cl, varlist= "dt2", envir = environment())
  clusterEvalQ(cl, library("data.table"))

  dt2 <- parallel::parLapply(cl, X= dt2, fun=instances_stacked)

  parallel::stopCluster(cl)
  return(rbindlist(dt2))
}
```

The call to foo2() will deploy the analysis in parallel and combine everything back together into `results_wide`.  We can then do the density calculation and view some results.

```
tic("foo2() runs on 4 data chunks (1/4 sized) in parallel: ")
results_wide <- foo2(tbl.data)
## next 4 lines done after the parallel part
results_wide[,calculation_1600:=sumCount_1600/(instances_1600*0.25)]
results_wide[,calculation_0800:=sumCount_0800/(instances_0800*0.25)]
results_wide[,calculation_0400:=sumCount_0400/(instances_0400*0.25)]
results_wide[,calculation_0200:=sumCount_0200/(instances_0200*0.25)]
toc()
## let's see the results
head(results_wide)
## for num.rows<-5e6, 
## should match the intro example at top of the post:
results_wide[UID==832751]
```

Which gives (after 42 1/2 hours):

```
> head(results_wide)
   UID instances_0200 sumCount_0200 instances_0400 sumCount_0400 instances_0800
1:   1             28         25348            115        110519            510
2:   2             38         37791            123        128978            498
3:   3             28         26958            123        131816            506
4:   4             33         33861            125        113013            514
5:   5             31         36492            123        130939            522
6:   6             37         40887            136        141213            480
   sumCount_0800 instances_1600 sumCount_1600 calculation_1600 calculation_0800
1:        521004           2025       2015967         3982.157         4086.306
2:        499358           2001       1999339         3996.680         4010.908
3:        507117           2013       2003329         3980.783         4008.830
4:        513712           2065       2115524         4097.867         3997.759
5:        516877           2054       1990644         3876.619         3960.743
6:        491969           1952       2001461         4101.355         4099.742
   calculation_0400 calculation_0200
1:         3844.139         3621.143
2:         4194.407         3978.000
3:         4286.699         3851.143
4:         3616.416         4104.364
5:         4258.179         4708.645
6:         4153.324         4420.216
```

```
## for num.rows <- 5e6, should match the 
## intro example at top of the post for
## Data[ID=="SC550650NE"]
> results_wide[UID==832751] 
      UID instances_0200 sumCount_0200 instances_0400 sumCount_0400
1: 832751             29         25463            122        110993
   instances_0800 sumCount_0800 instances_1600 sumCount_1600 calculation_1600
1:            480        467032           2048       2054509         4012.713
   calculation_0800 calculation_0400 calculation_0200
1:         3891.933         3639.115         3512.138
```

---

### Square metric

- e.g. Question Post's `(X-200, X+200) & (Y-200, Y+200)`

**...NOTE...I overloaded some function names so might be best to put this code in separate script and separate R session from the circle metric code**

Similar idea to `circle metric` approach above, but the execution is slightly different because it is based on the bounds as opposed to the distance.  Basically, we make a super stack of the data and calculate the boundaries specific for each distance.  These four "boundaries" make a natural candidate for chunking the data for parallelizing -- this code goes one step farther and breaks each of those 4 in half resulting in 8 groups. We still run on 4 nodes, though.  I tested a bunch on 8 nodes bc my testing environment allowed for this and I developed this code before I knew OP had a 4 core environment.

```
library(data.table)
library(tictoc)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
### Pick one:
### num.rows <- 4e4 ###     15 seconds on 8 nodes | 23 seconds on 4 nodes
 num.rows <- 1e5 ###        86 seconds on 8 nodes | 140.034 seconds on 4 nodes
### num.rows <- 2e5 ###    347 seconds on 8 nodes
### num.rows <- 4e5 ###   1370 seconds on 8 nodes   
### num.rows <- 8e5 ###   1370*4 =  90 minutes?
### num.rows <- 1.6e6 ###   1370*4*4 =  360 minutes = 6 hours (confirmed: 21742.233 / 60 / 60 = 6 hours)
### num.rows <- 2.5e6 ###     47523 / 60 / 60 = 13 hours and 12 minutes VERIFIED.
### num.rows <- 5.0e6 ###   4*47523 / 60 / 60 = ~53 hours estimated.

 # Input data
tbl.data <- data.table(
    X=runif(num.rows, min=200000, max=400000),
    Y=runif(num.rows, min=400000, max=500000),
    UID = 1:num.rows,
    Count = sample(1:2000,num.rows,replace=TRUE))

setkey(tbl.data, UID)

tbl.data

setkey(tbl.data, UID)
```

Make a superstack:

```
tbl.data.1600 <- copy(tbl.data)
tbl.data.0800 <- copy(tbl.data)
tbl.data.0400 <- copy(tbl.data)
tbl.data.0200 <- copy(tbl.data)

tbl.data.1600[, within_metric:=1600]
tbl.data.0800[, within_metric:= 800]
tbl.data.0400[, within_metric:= 400]
tbl.data.0200[, within_metric:= 200]

tbl.data.1600[, group:=1]
tbl.data.0800[, group:=2]
tbl.data.0400[, group:=3]
tbl.data.0200[, group:=4]

tbl.data.stack <- copy(rbind(tbl.data.1600, tbl.data.0800, tbl.data.0400, tbl.data.0200))


setkey(tbl.data.stack, group, UID)

tbl.data.stack[,X_low_bound:=X-within_metric]
tbl.data.stack[,X_upp_bound:=X+within_metric]

tbl.data.stack[,Y_low_bound:=Y-within_metric]
tbl.data.stack[,Y_upp_bound:=Y+within_metric]

Xvec <- tbl.data.stack[group==1]$X
Yvec <- tbl.data.stack[group==1]$Y
Cvec <- tbl.data.stack[group==1]$Count
```

I include this commented chunk -- this is how one could run it without parallelizing it.  Go ahead and skip for now to next block.

```
###################
## BEGIN ##########
###################
## no parallel. ###
## just stacked ###
###################


# instances_stacked <- function(x=Xvec,y=Yvec, count=Cvec, xlb, xub, ylb, yub){
#   
#   truth <- data.table::between(x, xlb, xub) & data.table::between(y, ylb, yub)
#   
#   c("instances" = sum( truth ), "sumCount"= sum( Cvec*truth))
#   
# }
# 
# 
# tic("external default vector approach -- STACKED -- all 4: ")
# results_stacked <- 
# tbl.data.stack[,
#          as.list(instances_stacked( xlb=X_low_bound, xub=X_upp_bound, ylb=Y_low_bound, yub=Y_upp_bound)),
#          by=c("group","UID")
# ]
# 
# results_stacked[,calculation:=sumCount/(instances*0.25)]
# toc()
# 
# head(results_stacked)

###################
## END.  ##########
###################
## no parallel. ###
## just stacked ###
###################
```

Below is the parallel code.  I broke into 8 groups, but changed the makeCluster line to 4 nodes for your computer.

```
###################
## BEGIN ##########
###################
## SOCKET.      ###
## ROCKET.      ###
###################
## follow the leader: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814035/2727349
## step 1: change instances_stacked (which is our `foo`) so that it returns a list.  Also change it to where
##           it takes data table as an argument.
## step 2: use split_df -- keep in mind might need to make a concatenated grouping of "group" and "UID"

instances <- function(x=Xvec,y=Yvec, count=Cvec, xlb, xub, ylb, yub){
  
  truth <- data.table::between(x, xlb, xub) & data.table::between(y, ylb, yub)
  
  c("instances" = sum( truth ), "sumCount"= sum( Cvec*truth))
  
  
  
  
}

instances_stacked <- function(DT, x=Xvec,y=Yvec, count=Cvec){
  
  
  DT[,
     as.list(instances( xlb=X_low_bound, xub=X_upp_bound, ylb=Y_low_bound, yub=Y_upp_bound)),
     by=c("within_metric","UID")
     ]

  
}

split_df <- function(d, var) {
  base::split(d, get(var, as.environment(d)))
}

## define grps to be distance-bound and UID combo
tbl.data.stack[,grps:=paste0(within_metric,"_",UID)]
tbl.data.stack[, uniqueN(grps)]

## define group_half to be distance-bound and UID < 1/2 num.rows
tbl.data.stack[,group_half:=paste0(within_metric,"_", (UID < 0.5 * num.rows)+0L)]
tbl.data.stack[, uniqueN(group_half)]

foo2 <- function(dt) {
  #dt2 <- split_df(dt, "grps")
  #dt2 <- split_df(dt, "group")
  dt2 <- split_df(dt, "group_half")
  
  require(parallel)
  ##cl <- parallel::makeCluster(min(nrow(dt), parallel::detectCores()))
  #cl <- parallel::makeCluster(tbl.data.stack[, uniqueN(group_half)])
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
  print(cl)
  clusterExport(cl, varlist= "instances_stacked") ## this was the `foo` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814035/2727349
    clusterExport(cl, varlist= "instances")
  clusterExport(cl, varlist= c("Xvec","Yvec","Cvec")) 
  clusterExport(cl, varlist= "dt2", envir = environment())
  clusterEvalQ(cl, library("data.table"))

  dt2 <- parallel::parLapply(cl, X= dt2, fun=instances_stacked)

  parallel::stopCluster(cl)
  return(rbindlist(dt2))
}

tic("external default vector approach -- SOCKET -- all 4 in parallel: ")

results_stacked_socket <- foo2(tbl.data.stack)

results_stacked_socket[,calculation:=sumCount/(instances*0.25)]
toc()

setkey(results_stacked_socket, UID, within_metric)
head(results_stacked_socket)

###################
## END.  ##########
###################
## SOCKET.      ###
## ROCKET.      ###
###################
```

Comment: The difference is because I am using the centroid location of the ID, rather than the exact location of each point in the dataset. So from the centroid location of SC550650NE  there are 20 points (including any assigned to SC550650NE) that are within 200m as assigned. In my answer you see I add a group ID to `Data` (this group is whatever 50m grid square it's in) and count how many points are in that. I then calculate the centroid location for these grid squares and assign that count to it. That's the dataset I use to calculate the answers.

Comment: I have not made it clear that this grouping has happened in my answer and doing it this way was a necessary compromise to cut down the number of unique permutations and get an answer that I could work with.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications.  As for distance, do you want the Question Post's (X-200, X+200) and (Y-200, Y+200) approach or your answer post's distance = sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) ) <= 200?  The first one is a square and the second is a circle, right?

Comment: Whatever works the best (which appears to be distance calculation). For my actual purposes, a method that works and can be explained is what’s important. My first attempt was more me avoiding going down the sf/spatial route, rather than the exact method I wanted sped-up

Comment: Yeah, the distance calc will be faster.  Also, for the density, would you want Count_200/(Instances_200*0.25) or Count_200/(Instances_200*0.000625)?

Comment: 0.25. 0.000625 was a mistake on my part

Comment: Thank you for these answers @swihart. They are both great, but are a lot slower on my machine unfortunately. Your 140.034 seconds on 4 nodes takes me 441.19 sec - but at least I know it can work without falling over so I can just leave it to do it's thing.

Comment: It's possible that breaking up the data into 6 or 8 or more chunks might speed things up a little bit.  I'm sorry that the timings didn't map over better.  After 42.5 hours on my machine, the circle metric finished.  `saveRDS(results_wide, "results_wide.RDS")` saved a <200mb file FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Jon Spring's comment I have used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750975/fastest-way-to-get-geo-distance-for-large-dataset-in-r/72755385#72755385) as inspiration to speed up the process. The following answer now takes around 12 hours to run on my real data (as opposed to the days/weeks the code in my question would have taken). It is a bit memory hungry at points (I am using a Windows desktop with 32GB of RAM) which is why I have minimised what gets stored (i.e. why I write out each loops output to CSV and then bring them back in at the end). Using `data.table` has definitely speed things up, but I am sure there will still be a quicker/more efficient way to do this - but this does what I need (even if my code is messy!).

```
# geosphere v1.5-19 required
install.packages('geosphere', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')

# Required libraries
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
   
set.seed(123)
   
# Input data
Data <- data.table(
    X=runif(5000000, min=200000, max=400000),
    Y=runif(5000000, min=400000, max=500000),
    UID = 1:5000000,
    Count = sample(1:2000,5000000,replace=TRUE))

# Add 50m grid cell ID for each point
Data[, ID := OSGB(Data[,c("X", "Y")], "50m")]   

# Summarise number of records for each 50m grid cell
Data_Summary <- Data[, .(Count = .N), by=.(ID)]

# Generate centroid coorindates for 50 metre grid squares that cover 'Data' extent
Coordinates <- CJ(X = seq((floor(min(Data$X)/1000)*1000)+25, ceiling(max(Data$X)/1000)*1000, 50),
                Y = seq((floor(min(Data$Y)/1000)*1000)+25, ceiling(max(Data$Y)/1000)*1000, 50))

# Add 50m grid cell ID for each centroid
Coordinates[, ID := OSGB(Coordinates[,c("X", "Y")], "50m")]

# Join 50m grid cell centroid coordinates to 'Data_Summary'
Data_Summary_with_Centroids <- Coordinates[Data_Summary, on = .(ID), nomatch = NULL]    

# Define maximum buffer size
Buffer <- 1650

# Generate offset XY coordinates for each grid centroid
Data_Summary_with_Centroids[,`:=`(X_NW = X-Buffer, Y_NW = Y+Buffer, 
                        X_NE = X+Buffer, Y_NE = Y+Buffer,
                        X_SW = X-Buffer, Y_SW = Y-Buffer,
                        X_SE = X+Buffer, Y_SE = Y-Buffer)]

# Assign 5km grid cell ID to all pairs of coordinates                       
Data_Summary_with_Centroids[,`:=`(HashCN = OSGB(Data_Summary_with_Centroids[,c("X", "Y")], "5km"), 
                        HashNW = OSGB(Data_Summary_with_Centroids[,c("X_NW", "Y_NW")], "5km"),
                        HashNE = OSGB(Data_Summary_with_Centroids[,c("X_NE", "Y_NE")], "5km"),
                        HashSW = OSGB(Data_Summary_with_Centroids[,c("X_SW", "Y_SW")], "5km"),
                        HashSE = OSGB(Data_Summary_with_Centroids[,c("X_SE", "Y_SE")], "5km"))]

# Remove offset XY coordinates
Data_Summary_with_Centroids[, c("X_NW", "Y_NW","X_NE", "Y_NE","X_SW", "Y_SW","X_SE", "Y_SE"):=NULL] 

Unique_5km_Hash <- unique(Data_Summary_with_Centroids$HashCN)

# List of all unique 5km grid cell IDs
Unique_5km_Hash <- unique(Data_Summary_with_Centroids$HashCN)

XY_Columns <- c("X", "Y")

for (n in 1:length(Unique_5km_Hash)){
    
    # Subset so only grid cells that have that loops 5km grid cell ID in any of HashCN, HashNW, HashNE, HashSW or HashSE remain
    Hash <- Data_Summary_with_Centroids[Data_Summary_with_Centroids[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `==`, Unique_5km_Hash[n])), 
    .SDcols = c("HashCN", "HashNW","HashNE","HashSW","HashSE")]][, c("HashNW", "HashNE","HashSW", "HashSE"):=NULL] 
    
    # Select only the columns needed for 'crossing'
    Hash_Cross <- Hash[, ..XY_Columns]

    # Expand to include all possible combinations of values
    suppressMessages(Hash_5km <- Hash_Cross %>% 
        crossing(., ., .name_repair = "unique"))
        
    rm(Hash_Cross)
    # Clear memory
    invisible(gc())
    
    # Calculate distances, disgard those over 1600m, keep only 'origin' records that are in 'HashCN' and add Count
    Hash_5km <- Hash_5km %>%
        mutate(Distance = sqrt((X...1 - X...3)^2 + (Y...2 - Y...4)^2)) %>%
        filter(Distance <=1600) %>%
        left_join(.,Hash %>% select(X, Y, ID, HashCN), join_by(X...1 == X, Y...2 == Y)) %>%
        filter(HashCN == Unique_5km_Hash[n]) %>%
        left_join(.,Hash %>% select(X, Y, Count), join_by(X...3 == X, Y...4 == Y)) %>%
        select(ID, Count, Distance)

    # Clear memory
    invisible(gc())

    # Create summary statistics of other grid cells within 200m
    Hash_200 <- Hash_5km %>%
        filter(Distance <=200) %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        summarise(Instances_200 = n(), Count_200 = sum(Count), Calculation_200 = Count_200/(Instances_200*0.25))

    # Create summary statistics of other grid cells within 400m
    Hash_400 <- Hash_5km %>%
        filter(Distance <=400) %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        summarise(Instances_400 = n(), Count_400 = sum(Count), Calculation_400 = Count_400/(Instances_400*0.25))

    # Create summary statistics of other grid cells within 800m 
    Hash_800 <- Hash_5km %>%
        filter(Distance <=800) %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        summarise(Instances_800 = n(), Count_800 = sum(Count), Calculation_800 = Count_800/(Instances_800*0.25))

    # Create summary statistics of other grid cells within 1600m    
    Hash_1600 <- Hash_5km %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        summarise(Instances_1600 = n(), Count_1600 = sum(Count), Calculation_1600 = Count_1600/(Instances_1600*0.25))

    # Join summary statistics together
    Output <- Hash_200 %>%
        left_join(Hash_400, by='ID') %>%
        left_join(Hash_800, by='ID') %>%
        left_join(Hash_1600, by='ID') 

    # Export output
    write_csv(Output, paste0("C:/Temp/Hash/",Unique_5km_Hash[n],".csv"))

    rm(Hash_5km)
    rm(Hash)
    rm(Hash_200)
    rm(Hash_400)
    rm(Hash_800)
    rm(Hash_1600)
    rm(Output)
    invisible(gc())
}

# Read in all CSV files into single 
Grid_Calculations <- list.files( path="C:/Temp/Hash/", , pattern = "*.csv", full.names=TRUE ) %>% 
  map_dfr(read_csv, show_col_types = FALSE)
```

**EDIT:** Have added set.seed() and slightly changed the start of the loop so only the relevant columns are used with 'crossing' (this makes it memory efficient for me).

**Output**

First five rows of first loop:

| ID | Instances_200 | Count_200 | Calculation_200 | Instances_400 | Count_400 | Calculation_400 | Instances_800 | Count_800 | Calculation_800 | Instances_1600 | Count_1600 | Calculation_1600 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SC550650NE | 20 | 24 | 4.8 | 88 | 119 | 5.4090909090909 | 360 | 475 | 5.27777777777777 | 1503 | 2041 | 5.43180306054557 |
| SC550650SW | 22 | 28 | 5.09090909090909 | 87 | 119 | 5.47126436781609 | 360 | 475 | 5.27777777777777 | 1500 | 2049 | 5.464 |
| SC550651NE | 20 | 30 | 6 | 86 | 117 | 5.44186046511627 | 364 | 479 | 5.26373626373626 | 1494 | 2032 | 5.44042838018741 |
| SC550651SE | 21 | 30 | 5.71428571428571 | 85 | 113 | 5.31764705882352 | 364 | 479 | 5.26373626373626 | 1491 | 2037 | 5.46478873239436 |
| SC550652NE | 28 | 42 | 6 | 85 | 113 | 5.31764705882352 | 369 | 485 | 5.25745257452574 | 1487 | 2020 | 5.43375924680564 |

Comment: Great progress! Another approach might be to sort one of your dimensions (e.g., the x coordinates) and keep an array to help keep track. For example, once your x is sorted, you would note where the differences are 200, 400, 800, and 1600 a way. You would scan through X once but you would have to fully evaluate the Y coordinates each time. It would take a bit of time to develop but should be more memory efficient and be more implementable in Rcpp. Just as a sample, in 1e6, the first point has 1000 neighbors within 200 m, so that's a lot less calculation for y you need to do.

Comment: So 12 hours is the time to beat?  Would it be possible to `set.seed(100)` before generated sim data and then posting the first few rows  of the desired/correct output with UID displayed?

Comment: When you run `parallel::detectCores()` on your machine, what is the answer?  It will help me customize my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @swihart I've added `set.seed(100)` and the first five rows of the output for the first loop. `detectCores()` is 4.

Comment: I have confirmed that `set.seed(123)` was used, as shown in the post.  I'll start working on this.  Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Take the first row, `ID==SC550650NE`, `Instances_200` has value of 20.  Is this just for this hash/loop?  Do you have a final answer for this ID (which is `UID==832751`)?

Comment: @swihart, that is both the answer for that loop and the final answer for that ID.  The first left join in `Hash_5km` and subsequent `filter(HashCN == Unique_5km_Hash[n])`  means that only points the originate in that ID are counted. That ID may come up again in further loops, but it will never be the origin, only within the buffer of a different ID.

Comment: Thanks @Chris.  Will you look at my "answer" which shows what my answer would be for the top row first two columns and point out what I'm missing?  I feel like the approach in this answer is an approximation (?) and the solution I was working up off the original question was exact and will get you the answer in 52 hours or so...any interest?

Comment: @swihart very much of interest. A couple of days or so I can work with!

Answer (score 1):

Being the man who says there must be people who can do it better than me, I would look for solutions made by others.

So I see some advantages in using the `sf` and `spdep` packages. Both are explicitly designed for spatial data.

There are two functions to start with.

Create an sf-object

```
x <- sf::st_as_sf(Data, coords = c("X", "Y"))
```

and the distances could be done with the

```
st_distance()
```

Surely a solution has to be found that does not compute all the distances. A simple algorithm is to sort the points into bins of half the size of the desired radius. Then you only need to check the points in neighbouring bins.

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table could help .. but for this case, i think the calculation time will still be far too huge ..

May be you want to try anyway :

```
library(data.table)
tbl.data <- as.data.table(Data)

tbl.data[, Instances_200 := mapply(function (x,y) {tbl.data[X<x+200 & X > x -200
                                                               & Y < y+200 & Y > y -200, .N ]}, X, Y)]

tbl.data[, Count_200 := mapply(function (x,y) {tbl.data[X<x+200 & X > x -200
                                                            & Y < y+200 & Y > y -200, sum(Count) ]}, X, Y)]

tbl.data[, Calculation_200 := Count_200/(Instances_200*0.000625)]
```

And so on.